# cmpl of a constant to the value in the register looks correct but fails

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, memory-address, disassembly

I am debugging some assembly code and have a comparison that fails even though the constant value of 1 is equal to the value in the register it is being compared to.

Here is the compare:

```
=> 0x0000000000400f0a <+14>:    cmpl   $0x1,(%rsp)
```

Here is a dump of my registers and the value in the register:

```
(gdb) i r
rax            0x6                 6
...
...
rsp            0x7fffffffdf80      0x7fffffffdf80
...
...
```

The value at that address is:

```
(gdb) x/d 0x7fffffffdf80
0x7fffffffdf80: 1
```

Any ideas why this compare is failing? I looked through the memory allocated for that stack frame and it all looks correct with 4-byte values and 1 at the beginning of the frame. Any ideas why the comparison of 1 and 1 fail? My condition flags don't have the ZF set. I am new to assembly but I think this should be set as the compl subtraction operation will set it. My eflags are:

eflags         0x206               [ PF IF ]

Comment: At which point do you check `eflags`?

Comment: Good call @ssbssa. I was running it before the compare. When I check just after the cmpl the zero flag is set:

eflags         0x246               [ PF ZF IF ]

I assume the parity and interrupt flags are not relevant. The next instruction is a je:

0x0000000000400f0e <+18>: je     0x400f30

The je should be true and the jump performed if the ZF is set correct? That isn't what is happening though. The jump is skipped and the next instruction crashes my program. Do I have an incorrect understanding of how cmpl the ZF and je interact?

Comment: Make sure you are properly single stepping (`si`).